# Ionic Music seekbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, playback

I want to know if there's a way to create a seekbar for a music player in ionic.

I'm currently using cordova-media plugin to play music and I want to know how to implement seeking(dragging to move to a particular position in a song).

I tried using a rangeslider and set it's value to an ng-model that is bonded to the current position of the song. This works okay when the song starts(It moves as the song is playing) but when you skip to a particular position(by dragging the slider), it moves to that position and plays the song from that position(as is expected) but the slider stops moving with the current position of the song.

```
<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="100" ng-model="sliderPercentage" ng-value="{{sliderPercentage}}" style="width:100%" ng-change="seekTrack(sliderPercentage)">
```

Here's the javascript:

```
  $rootScope.sliderInterval = $interval(function () {
    $rootScope.media.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      if (position > 0) {
        var dur = $rootScope.media.getDuration();
        $rootScope.sliderPercentage = (position / dur) * 100;
        console.log('Position: ' + position + '\nDuration: ' + dur);
        console.log($rootScope.sliderPercentage);
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
```

Is there a better way of implementing a seekbar or a way to make this current one work?